# Create a list with powershell

Tags: 2010, list, powershell

I need to create one list with powershell with the following columns

Title
Url (255 max length)
Description (255 max length)

It must be a custom list.  There is no need to create site columns or content type, just the list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I find it strange that you have done no basic research before posting this. Googling "create list powershell" will find you [this post](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/09/22/use-powershell-to-manage-lists-views-and-items-in-sharepoint.aspx) from heyscriptingguy, which should be what you need to get started.

```
PS > $listTemplate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListTemplateType]::GenericList 
PS > $spListCollection = $spWeb.Lists 
PS > $spListCollection.Add("My Generic List","Description",$listTemplate)
PS > $spList = $spWeb.Lists["My Generic List"]
PS > $spFieldType = [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldType]::Text 
PS > $spList.Fields.Add("TextField",$spFieldType,$false)
```

Comment: I think you've missed a line (assigning the list to $spList), +1 though as I found your script useful.