# Recreate a List in many subsites of a site collection using powershell

Tags: list, powershell

I have to recreate the same List in several subsites within a site collection. I saved my List as a template but it will be very time consuming to add the List manually to all of my subsites using the SharePoint GUI. Can anyone point me to a good article or provide a sample of how to do this using PowerShell?

Thanks in advance,
Jovi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you have added list as a stp file in List template gallery:

```
    $site = Get-SPSite http://site
    foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {    
    $listTemplates = $site.GetCustomListTemplates($web)
    $web.Lists.Add("Your name for list", "", $listTemplates["Your List template name"])
    }
```

Remember, you can't pass the template ID in the `Add` method but you can easily query on template IDs using PowerShell:'

```
$web = Get-SPWeb "http://serverUrl"
$template = $web.ListTemplates | Where-Object {$_.Type -eq 10100}
# Now add the list using the retrieved template object...
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to create a script that worked. I just have one last question. I searched for the answer but did find anything. The lists that were created did not appear on the quick launch, is there a parameter I can use to do this in powershell. So I don't have to go into the List Setting and manually set the "Display this list on the Quick Launch" to yes.

Comment: $list.OnQuickLaunch = $True

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of creating a list:
[Create a list with powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/30238/create-a-list-with-powershell)

Then this script will loop through each site in the site collection

```
$siteURL = "http://sp14fdev01/"
$site = Get-SPSite($siteURL)

foreach($web in $site.AllWebs) {
}
```

Simply add your list creation code inside the foreach. Note you will want to check to make sure the list doesn't already exist.